# Adding directories to resources folders in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

If I have a large project with many resources, is there anyway to organise them using directories?  I tired adding directories to drawable/ but it didn't work.

Comment: You can put directories in the Asset folder. Would that do the trick for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You cannot have subdirectories inside a resource directory. Sorry!

Comment: I want to up and down this at the same time!  Up because it's the right answer and down because that sucks!